# JSON.stringify with DataTables - getting Invalid JSON response

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, datatables

I'm not very proficient with JS/HTML. I needed to get the table in JSON from Firebase and show it nicely using DataTables.
I have a working code getting data from Firebase after JSON.stringify as:

```
[{
    "Rings": 0,
    "P_Bars": 0,
    "First_Name": "Jane",
    "Last_Name": "Dow",
    "Vault": 10,
    "Number": 101,
    "H_Bar": 0,
    "Level": "4_A",
    "Pommel": 11.402,
    "Floor": 0
}, {
    "Pommel": 12.5,
    "Vault": 7,
    "Floor": 11.5,
    "Level": "6_Optional",
    "P_Bars": 10,
    "H_Bar": 0,
    "Number": 102,
    "First_Name": "Steve",
    "Last_Name": "Dark",
    "Rings": 12
}]
```

And I'm having the following error:

> DataTables warning: table id=test - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

My JS code:

```
async function GetAllDataRealtime() {
  const dbRef = collection(db, "Gymnasts");

  onSnapshot(dbRef, (querySnapshot) => {
    var gymnasts = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      gymnasts.push(doc.data());
    });
    return JSON.stringify(gymnasts);
  });
}

var testdata = GetAllDataRealtime();

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#test").DataTable({
    ajax: {
      "data": testdata,
      "dataType": "json",
    },
    columns: [
      { data: "Number" },
      { data: "First_Name" },
      { data: "Last_Name" },
      { data: "Rings" },
      { data: "Floor" },
      { data: "Pommel" },
      { data: "H_Bar" },
      { data: "P_Bars" },
      { data: "Vault" },
    ],
  });
});
```

And HTML *(I don't think the problem is here though)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Test</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="db.js"></script> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="test" class="display" style="width: 100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Number</th>
          <th>First_Name</th>
          <th>Last_Name</th>
          <th>Rings</th>
          <th>Floor</th>
          <th>Pommel</th>
          <th>H_Bar</th>
          <th>P_Bars</th>
          <th>Vault</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to use a dedicated .json file an it works.
Based on https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/1 *(from the Error message) I investigated the XHR/Request-Response and I cannot even see a proper response in the logs although consoling the "testdata" showing the correct array. Tested with JSON validator - all good. It feels I'm missing something here.

Comment: Statements like "please help" and "thanks" are considered noise on SO, and should not be added to a question.

Answer (score 2):

Data is loaded from Firestore (and most cloud APIs) asynchronously, but your code fails to handle that.

You have two asynchronous events in your code:

1. The document itself loads asynchronously.
2. The data from Firestore is loaded asynchronously.

Your code needs to handle this asynchronous nature, for example: by only creating the data table when the the document is ready and when the data has been loaded from Firestore.

In code that could be done like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  const dbRef = collection(db, "Gymnasts");

  onSnapshot(dbRef, (querySnapshot) => {
    var gymnasts = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      gymnasts.push(doc.data());
    });

    $("#test").DataTable({
      ajax: {
        "data": gymnasts,
        "dataType": "json",
      },
      columns: [
        { data: "Number" },
        { data: "First_Name" },
        { data: "Last_Name" },
        { data: "Rings" },
        { data: "Floor" },
        { data: "Pommel" },
        { data: "H_Bar" },
        { data: "P_Bars" },
        { data: "Vault" },
      ],
    });

  });
});
```

So here we only start loading the data once the document is read, and then set the data table once the data is available. Since you're using an `onSnapshot` realtime listener, the data table will be updated when the underlying data is updated.

---

I highly recommend reading up and taking some tutorials on asynchronous behavior before continuing, as this is an incredibly common source of confusion - and you're likely to get stuck on it many times until you grok async code.

Answer (score 0):

I have parsed the JSON data and put into the DataTable as described in the [documentation](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html) and it works for me!

Check out the below solution:

```js
let data = JSON.parse("[{\"Rings\": 0,\"P_Bars\": 0,\"First_Name\": \"Jane\",\"Last_Name\": \"Dow\",\"Vault\": 10,\"Number\": 101,\"H_Bar\": 0,\"Level\": \"4_A\",\"Pommel\": 11.402,\"Floor\": 0}, {\"Pommel\": 12.5,\"Vault\": 7,\"Floor\": 11.5,\"Level\": \"6_Optional\",\"P_Bars\": 10,\"H_Bar\": 0,\"Number\": 102,\"First_Name\": \"Steve\",\"Last_Name\": \"Dark\",\"Rings\": 12}]");

$(document).ready(function () {
  new DataTable('#test', {
    data: data,
    columns: [
      { data: "Number" },
      { data: "First_Name" },
      { data: "Last_Name" },
      { data: "Rings" },
      { data: "Floor" },
      { data: "Pommel" },
      { data: "H_Bar" },
      { data: "P_Bars" },
      { data: "Vault" },
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<table id="test" class="display" style="width: 100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>First_Name</th>
      <th>Last_Name</th>
      <th>Rings</th>
      <th>Floor</th>
      <th>Pommel</th>
      <th>H_Bar</th>
      <th>P_Bars</th>
      <th>Vault</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```